# Laravel 5 - get MIME type from file extension

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mime

In Laravel 5 how can I get MIME type from extension? Even better if there's a way to convert array of extensions to array of mimes.

E.g. how to convert `array('doc', 'xls')` to `array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-excel')`?

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types This file contains all MIME types and their extensions. You just need to search for the extensions programmatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0" is in your composer.json, you can use this:

```
$mimetype = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\mimetype_from_filename('foo.doc');
$mimetype = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\mimetype_from_extension('doc');
```

Comment: From function phpdoc:
`@deprecated mimetype_from_filename will be removed in guzzlehttp/psr7:2.0. Use MimeType::fromFilename instead.`

Answer (score 8):

Simply the best in L5:

```
\File::mimeType('physical/path/to/file.ext');
```

Comment: note that this requires the file to exist and it's unable to detect the mime type just by the file extension contained in the string

Answer (score 8):

## to get file mimetype

```
$request->file->getMimeType()
```

## validation code

```
$request->validate([
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
    'mp3'=>'required|mimetypes:audio/mpeg'
   ]);
```

you can get the file type from above code, after that you can set that to ***mimetypes*** like set for mp3

Answer (score 4):

[Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/) is included in Laravel 5 by default, there's the [list of mime types](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Mimetypes.php) in this library and `fromExtension()` method which do exaclty what was asked.

So, to get MIME type of single extension:

```php
$mimetypes = new \GuzzleHttp\Mimetypes;

$mime = $mimetypes->fromExtension($extension);
```

To get array of MIME types from array of extensions:

```php
$mimetypes = new \GuzzleHttp\Mimetypes;

$mimes = [];
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $mimes[] = $mimetypes->fromExtension($extension);
}
```

Comment: FYI as of Guzzle 6.0 `GuzzleHttp\Mimetypes` has been moved to a function in `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\mimetype_from_extension` and `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\mimetype_from_filename`

Answer (score 3):

```
MimeType::from('koala_transparent.png')
```

return "image/png"

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to download this public domain file: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Then use the following function to read the file and get the corresponding `MIME` type for an extension:

```
function getMIME($extension) {
    $file = "mime.types";
    $in = fopen($file, "r");
    while (($line = fgets($in)) !== false) {
        if (preg_match("/([a-z]+\/[a-z]+)\s+([a-z\s]*)\b($extension)\b/", $line, $match)) {
            return $match[1];
        }
    }
    fclose($in);
    return "error";
}

echo getMIME("doc");
```

Output:

> application/msword

To convert the array:

```
$myArray = array('doc', 'xls');

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    $myArray[$key] = getMIME($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0 of the PSR7 API `mimetype_from_filename` was replaced by `MimeType::fromFilename`.

This works for me in Laravel 8.x

```
$mimeType = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MimeType::fromFilename($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

https://github.com/ralouphie/mimey

it can give mimetype by extension **without existing file**